# Check that the Lebesgue $\sigma$-field is a $\sigma$-field

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$$
Let $\mathcal{L}(\R)$ be the collection of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\R$.
That is,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(\R) = \{E\subseteq\R:m^*(A) = m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\cap E^\complement),\;\forall A\subseteq\R\}.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
I want to check that $\mathcal{L}(\R)$ is a $\sigma$-field.
It is clear that plugging $E\gets\R$ into $(*)$ gives $\R\in \mathcal{L}(\R)$ and also that if $E\in\mathcal{L}(\R)$ then $E^\complement\in\mathcal{L}(\R)$, but I have difficulty showing the countable union property.
Explicitly, I am trying to show that if $E_n\in\mathcal{L}(\R)$ for $n\geq1$, then $E:=\bigcup_{n\geq1}E_n\in\mathcal{L}(\R)$.
My approach is as follows:

Consider any $A\subseteq\R$.
Then
\begin{align}
m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\cap E^\complement) &= m^*\left(A\cap\big[\cup_{n\geq1}E_n\big]\right) + m^*\left(A\cap\big[\cup_{n\geq1}E_n\big]^\complement\right)\\
&=m^*\left(\overbrace{\bigcup_{n\geq1}\big[A\cap E_n\big]}^{D_1}\right) + m^*\left(\overbrace{\bigcap_{n\geq1}\big[A\cap E_n^\complement\big]}^{D_2}\right)
\end{align}
and I want to use the definition of outer measure
$$m^*(D) := \inf_{D\subseteq \bigcup_{j\geq1} B_j} \sum_{j=1}^\infty m(B_j)$$
for $D_1$ and $D_2$ to eventually show $m^*(D_1)+m^*(D_2)=m^*(A)$, but I am stuck.
Does it work to say that "$\leq$" holds because there can be two separate covers for $D_1$ and $D_2$ and "$\geq$" holds by countable subadditivity of $m^*$?

Comment: This is Caratheodory's theorem and it holds for any outer measure, not just Lebesgue outer measure. You can first show that $L(\mathbb{R})$ is closed under finite unions (and is hence an algebra), then establish finite additivity (which easily yields countable additivity), then establish closure under countable disjoint unions. Then you are done.

Comment: @Mason: ohh, thank you , i didn't realize this!